# MVC ViewModel, using a VM with some properies marked required, depending if its a GET or POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, viewmodel, modelstate

I've often found myself fixing validations for the modelstate manually, due to the inconsistency of some fields that are required in a view model during post and get.

Supposing I've got this View Model:

```
public class RestaurantMenuName_ViewModel
{        
    public Int64 RestaurantMenuNameId { get; set; }

    public Int64 OwnerId{ get; set; }

    public string MenuNameCategory { get; set; }

    public string CategoryDescription { get; set; }

    public bool IsFormSaved { get; set; }
}
```

During a **GET** request the controller/Action requires the validation of just the fields, RestaurantMenuNameId and OwnerId. When calling the Action RestaurantMenuName, the query string values are RestaurantMenuNameId and OwnerId. Modelstate validation will be done on:

- RestaurantMenuNameId
- OwnerId

During a **POST** request the controller/Action will require the modelstate validation of the fields:

- RestaurantMenuNameId
- OwnerId
- MenuNameCategory
- CategoryDescription

This is the inconsistency issue I'm talking about, a solution could be using a ViewModel for Get requests and one for Post, but this could be real a time waster and error prone. Using ViewBag is out of discussion.

**Question:**
Is there a way to tell MVC that we want some fields [required] for GET and other for POST?

The following is a Pseudo-code of what I'm talking about:

```
 public class RestaurantMenuName_ViewModel
{   
    [Required: in GET, POST]  //<--Pseudo code
    public Int64 RestaurantMenuNameId { get; set; }

    [Required: in GET, POST]  //<--Pseudo code
    public Int64 OwnerId { get; set; }

    [Required: in POST]       //<--Pseudo code
    public string MenuNameCategory { get; set; }

    [Required: in POST]       //<--Pseudo code
    public string CategoryDescription { get; set; }

    public bool IsFormSaved { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you passing complex objects to GET methods? If so don't! Your parameter should just be the `id`

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, yep, I know but there are some special cases where passing a complex object to GET is bad practice but more practical.

Comment: why would you want to pass a complex object to a get, just pass the required ids

Comment: From your comments I guess there is no way to flag ViewModel properties with a GET/POST Required or do something similar.

Comment: It's not so much bad practice as impractical.  If your GET is the viewmodel you posted, what does it mean if the calling code sets and passed in `MenuNameCategory` to the GET - is it just ignored?  (Most likely).   What about `IsFormSaved`?  I want to GET with the form already saved - is that allowed or ignored?  No way to tell even if you do have a *Required*-on-Get, that's not clear that it's *ignored*-on-get.  It makes no sense to _allow_ these to be passed to the GET action, other than just being lazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a very good practice (and confusing in your case) to pass complex objects when you need only few properties. It will be better to pass only the required ids as primitives.

If the case is special and you really need the complex objects, it will be better to create two different view models for every request and decorate the required properties accordingly.

However, you can create your own require validation attribute which will validate properties dependening on the current request.

```
public class MyRequiredAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private string httpVerb;

    public MyRequiredAttribute(string httpVerb)
    {
        this.httpVerb = httpVerb;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if(HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == this.httpVerb)
        {
            return value != null;
        }

        return true;
    }
}

// Usage
public class MyViewModel
{
    [MyRequired("GET")]
    public string A { get; set; }

    [MyRequired("POST")]
    public string B { get; set; }
}
```

**Note**: you can use an enumeration to avoid some difficulties (ex. upper case, lower case, misspelling etc.) and also you can override the `FormatErrorMessage` method to change the default error message and format it properly.